# How to store all json object values in arraylist?

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

I have following response...from this response i am parsing bulkprice array and its objects,now what I am trying is that I need to store all the minqty values in one arraylist and want to convert all those values in Integer..but I am not able to get that..

```
{"status":"success","clientproduct":[{"pid":"4","name":"kangan pair","unitprice":"1500","boxqty":"1","bulkprice":[{"minqty":"10","price":"1500"},{"minqty":"15","price":"1470"},{"minqty":"20","price":"1460"}]}]}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();

         try {
             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid",letss));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "clientproduct"));

             System.out.println("????"+params);

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 FEEDBACK_URL, "POST", params);
             //check your log for json response
               Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json.toString());

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    clientproduct = jsonObj.getJSONArray(CLIENTPRODUCT_LIST);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < clientproduct.length(); i++) {
                       ck = clientproduct.getJSONObject(i);

                       unitp=ck.getString("unitprice");
                        System.out.println("Unit ni price"+unitp);

                       boxq=ck.getString("boxqty");
                        System.out.println("Box ni quantity "+boxq);

                        bulkprice = ck.getJSONArray(BULKPRICE_LIST);

                        allqtys=new ArrayList<String>();
                         for (int b=0 ; b < bulkprice.length(); b++)
                         {
                             jo = bulkprice.getJSONObject(b);

                           minimum_qty=jo.getString("minqty");
                        allqtys.add(minimum_qty);
                            /* allqtys=new ArrayList<String>();
                           allqtys.add(minimum_qty.toString());
                          System.out.println("All MinQuantitiy"+minimum_qty);*/
                     System.out.println("All MinQuantitiy"+allqtys);
                       System.out.println("MinQuantitiy"+minimum_qty);

                           pricess=jo.getString("price");
                            System.out.println("Box price "+pricess);

                         }
                         /*conrs=Integer.parseInt(allqtys.toString());
                         System.out.println("Integer converted arrray"+conrs);*/

                        /* newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(allqtys.size()) ;
                         for (String myInt : allqtys) 
                         { 
                           newList.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt)); 
                         }
                         System.out.println("allqtys "+newList);*/

                        System.out.println("Not Null");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }


         return json.getString(FEEDBACK_SUCCESS);

     }catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;
}

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

       /* ArrayList<Integer> allval=new ArrayList<Integer>();
       // allval.add(minimum_qty);
       System.out.println("Integer converted arraylist"+allval);*/


        autoproduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // uprice.setText(unitp);
                    //bxqtyy.setText(boxq);
            }
        });


        bxqtyy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(Integer.parseInt(bxqtyy.getText().toString()) > allqtys)
                {
                    if(bxqtyy.getText().equals(null))
                    {
                        uprice.setText(unitp);
                    }
                    uprice.setText("1470");
                    //System.out.println("lets check");
                }
                else
                {
                    uprice.setText("1500");
                    System.out.println("lets check");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });

}}
```

Logcat

```
04-29 13:16:52.579: I/System.out(953): All MinQuantitiy[10]
04-29 13:16:52.609: I/System.out(953): MinQuantitiy10
 04-29 13:16:52.639: I/System.out(953): Box price 1500
04-29 13:16:52.639: I/System.out(953): All MinQuantitiy[10, 15]
04-29 13:16:52.639: I/System.out(953): MinQuantitiy15
04-29 13:16:52.639: I/System.out(953): Box price 1470
 04-29 13:16:52.679: I/System.out(953): All MinQuantitiy[10, 15, 20]
04-29 13:16:52.709: I/System.out(953): MinQuantitiy20
04-29 13:16:52.709: I/System.out(953): Box price 1460
```

Comment: If your JSONObject is returned correctly just int minimum_qty=jo.getInt("minqty");

Comment: @M090009 then i need store it in arraylist too..

Comment: @chris you need all the minqty in a single arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> minqtyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

JSONArray array = ck.getJSONArray(BULKPRICE_LIST);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    int minqty = row.getInt("minqty");
    minqtyList.add(minqty);
}
```

---

In your code, you need to edit this portion like that:

```
bulkprice = ck.getJSONArray(BULKPRICE_LIST);
allqtys=new ArrayList<String>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop

for (int b=0 ; b < bulkprice.length(); b++){
    jo = bulkprice.getJSONObject(b);
    minimum_qty=jo.getString("minqty");
    allqtys.add(minimum_qty);

    System.out.println("All MinQuantitiy"+minimum_qty);
    System.out.println("MinQuantitiy"+minimum_qty);

    pricess=jo.getString("price");// here you'll get only the last value. otherwise you need to use a list, like you did with "minqty"
    System.out.println("Box price "+pricess);
}
```

Comment: i edit as per your second code..but it shows not in arraylist

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows not in arraylist"? in your log i can see the 3 values of  *minqty* (10,15,20)

Comment: Accept the answer if it solve your problem. And for your question, i haven't understand where you want to update unitPrice from 1500 to 1470, if you talk about updating the json you need to re-create your clientproduct JsonArray with the new value of  unitprice.

Comment: If you have another question you need to create another one, don't update the current. To not confuse future users and the coherence between the question and the accepted answer. Read about  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you to use a JSONArray for your json values and to iterate through them:

```
String strJSON = ""; // your string goes here
List<int> minqtys = new ArrayList<int>();

JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(new StringReader(strJSON)) {
    JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
    JsonArray results = obj.getJsonArray("bulkprice");
    for (JsonObject result : results.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {
         int minqty = Integer.parseInt(result.getString("minqty"));
         minqtys.add(minqty);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code..

```
String json="{\"status\":\"success\",\"clientproduct\":[{\"pid\":\"4\",\"name\":\"kangan pair\",\"unitprice\":\"1500\",\"boxqty\":\"1\",\"bulkprice\":[{\"minqty\":\"10\",\"price\":\"1500\"},{\"minqty\":\"15\",\"price\":\"1470\"},{\"minqty\":\"20\",\"price\":\"1460\"}]}]}";

        String json1="{\"status\":\"success\",\"clientproduct\":[{\"pid\":\"4\",\"name\":\"kangan pair\",\"unitprice\":\"1500\",\"boxqty\":\"1\",\"bulkprice\":[{\"minqty\":\"10\",\"price\":\"1500\"},{\"minqty\":\"15\",\"price\":\"1470\"},{\"minqty\":\"20\",\"price\":\"1460\"}]},{\"pid\":\"6\",\"name\":\"Mala\",\"unitprice\":\"1500\",\"boxqty\":\"1\",\"bulkprice\":\"\"}]}";
        JSONObject jsonobj;
        List<HashMap<String,String>> minqty_list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        try {
            jsonobj = new JSONObject(json1);
            JSONArray client_product=jsonobj.getJSONArray("clientproduct");
            for(int i=0;i<client_product.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject client_prod=client_product.getJSONObject(i);
                try
                {
                JSONArray bulkprice=client_prod.getJSONArray("bulkprice");

                for(int j=0;j<bulkprice.length();j++)
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> hs=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hs.put("bulk",bulkprice.getJSONObject(j).getString("minqty"));
                    minqty_list.add(hs);
                }
                }catch(JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(minqty_list.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

in your above code change this to

```
JSONArray bulkprice=client_prod.getJSONArray("bulkprice");
                       for(int j=0;j<bulkprice.length();j++)
                       {
                           minqty_list.add(Integer.parseInt(bulkprice.getJSONObject(j).getString("minqty")));
                       }
```

to this

```
try
                {
                JSONArray bulkprice=client_prod.getJSONArray("bulkprice");

                for(int j=0;j<bulkprice.length();j++)
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> hs=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hs.put("bulk",bulkprice.getJSONObject(j).getString("minqty"));
                    minqty_list.add(hs);
                }
                }catch(JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: it shows org.json.JSONException: Value  at bulkprice of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: @chris i run this code ...it worked for your json string... if you are trying with another json string plz post it...

Comment: see my edited code in question..i edit as per your answer..and it shows..org.json.JSONException: Value at bulkprice of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: @chris you have to check if the bulkprice is jsonarray or not.. for that surround the statement with try catch .. it won't consider if the bulkprice is not a jsonarray..

Comment: but did you see in my code that,in the same doinbackground i need to send some of fields to server..so will it affect?

Comment: what? i dint get you?

Comment: why you use json1?..and sorry its not working..cuz in my this activity i am using two autocompletetextview also..and i need to send id of first autocompletetextview's json to get second autocompletetextview json..so may be it wont work..thnks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this, by using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Example:

```
 List<CustomObject> myList = gson.fromJson(br, new
 TypeToken<List<CustomObject>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun loadFontsFromJson(context: Context): ArrayList<String> {
        val fontList = ArrayList<String>()
        val json: String
        try {
            val inputStream = context.assets.open("font_list.json")
            val size = inputStream.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            inputStream.read(buffer)
            inputStream.close()
            json = kotlin.String()
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)
            val fontArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("fontList")
            for (i in 0 until fontArray.length()) {
                val font = fontArray.getString(i)
                fontList.add(font)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return fontList
    }
```